# JsonRpcProvider Error when deploying contract or Trying to run a node

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

The error is as follows

```
Error: ERROR processing skip func of /home/dylan/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
```

I am following along the freecodecamp tutorial and I did this TWICE. I thought maybe I mistyped something terribly. But no it still doesn't work. I remade the directory so I'm assuming its not a install/dependency issue but I'm a noob so who knows. I searched and tried some tips surrounding this error but I could not find a solution. I'm lost please help, I'll upload my js files below. Please request more if you think they will help.

00-deploy-mocks.js

```
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const BASE_FEE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25")
const GAS_PRICE_LINK = 1e9

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const args = [BASE_FEE, GAS_PRICE_LINK]
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        log("local network detected! deploying mocks...")
        await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", {
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: args,
        })
        log("Mocks Deployed!")
        log("----------------------------------------")
    }
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

01-deploy-raffle.js

```
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("2")
module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        //Fund the sub
        //usually oyud need the link token
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }

    const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
    const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
    const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
    const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]

    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        entranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callbackGasLimit,
        interval,
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, args)
    }
    log("----------------------------------")
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]
```

hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("hardhat-contract-sizer")
require("dotenv").config()

const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
            blockConfirmations: 1,
        },
        goerli: {
            chainId: 5,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.7",
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0,
        },
        player: {
            default: 1,
        },
    },
}
```

helper-hardhat-config.js

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

const networkConfig = {
    5: {
        name: "goerli",
        vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D",
        entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane: "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15",
        subscriptionId: "0",
        callbackGasLimit: "500000",
        interval: "30",
    },
    31337: {
        name: "hardhat",
        entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane: "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15",
        callbackGasLimit: "500000",
        interval: "30",
    },
}

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]

module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the version of ethers to ^5.7.2 in `package.json`. I had version 6.6.0 installed and changing it to ^5.7.2 fixed this error.
After that, delete the `node_modules` folder and run `yarn` to install the packages again.